# How to select and copy a part of the text of an hyperlink in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

When you receive an HTML mail in Mail.app, how can you select a part of the text of an hyperlink in order to copy it to tha pasteboard ?

The only way I found is to display the mail is to diplay the mail in another form (raw source, plain text alternative), search this and copy ? Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but when a link is displayed in Mail, if you want to select only a part of it, one trick is to put the cursor slightly to the left or to the right of the link (not too far though, or you'll select spaces too) and select the link's text from this point.

Thus, the cursor will be in 'select' mode, and you're going to be able to select a part of the text from the link. This only works if you're wanting to select the beginning of the end of it though.

Comment: I know this method, but it's really painful to use. And I want to select one word inside the link. Like alt+click in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I find it easy to start to drag and select from the right for example, and then once I have the section I'm after, a usual <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd-V</kbd> to where the content needs to go suffices after that.

Just confirmed this works quite well in 10.8.2 Mail App with a test email.